# Add .setBadge to a ImageView in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

[image: Badge on top of an image]

I need to add a badge like the added picture. the badge needs to be above an imageView. how can i implement that in Titanium. I'm not using the alloy folder

Comment: Is your intention to add the badge to an image view inside your app or to add the badge to your icon on the iOS home screen?

Comment: my intension is to add the badge to an image inside my app. can i add badges to an android app to or only in iOS app's?

Comment: As far as adding a badge to an app's launch icon, you can only do that in iOS. In regards to doing it to an image view inside your app, I'm less familiar with an efficient way to accomplish that (and it has been a couple years since I've used Titanium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manuel_Rodrigues. There's no a good way to accomplish the effect you want, but there's a compromise method to get the similar effect. In this way you can consider that the **badge** is a image too, so just put the badge upon the **background image** can accomplish the effect. In **Titanium**, it called ***MaskedImage*** which combine too images or just render a image with various blend mode. Well, I don't have a try but maybe it can help you. Check for this [***link***](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101), you'll get more details!

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler solution... Place the Image in a View (we'll call this parent view `pView`). Make sure `pView.layout = 'absolute';`

Add the Badge as a Label (we'll call it `bLabel`) inside `pView`.

```
bLabel.width = Ti.UI.SIZE; // so it can enlarge depending on label's text
bLabel.height = 16; // depends on font size
bLabel.borderRadius = 16 / 2; // half the height
bLabel.backgroundColor = 'red';
bLabel.color = 'white';
```

bLabel.x & y where you want to place this badge within pView, over the Image. If you want the badge to be on top right outside the image, make `pView` larger than the image.

You may need to hardcode of with & heights of the pView if you're not sure of the height / width of the image (say remote image), you'll have to create the pView and bLabel dynamically on `complete` event of the image as its being downloaded remotely (we won't know the size of the image till complete is fired).